# How to override keybindings for `term`

Tags: keymap, term

For some tasks like using ruby's `pry` and `tmux` both `eshell` and `shell` do not behave well. I tried to use `term`, but my innability to override the keybindings in `term` makes its use annoying.

How can I set, say, `M-o` as `other-window` and `M-k` as `kill-buffer` when using `term` ?

Comment: My keybindings work in `term` but only in line mode `C-c C-j`. I just toggle char mode `C-c C-k` whenever necessary.

Comment: I didn't knew about `C-c C-j` and `C-c C-k`! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe using `ansi-term` instead would be slightly less annoying, since it exposes a `C-x` prefix, allowing you to use, say, `C-x o` or `C-x k` without any special trick.

If that's not sufficient, you can use the following approach:

```
(defun expose-global-binding-in-term (binding)
   (define-key term-raw-map binding 
     (lookup-key (current-global-map) binding)))

(expose-global-binding-in-term (kbd "M-o"))
(expose-global-binding-in-term (kbd "M-k"))
...
```

Answer (score 8):

In term-mode, any regular `C-x whatever` keybinding becomes `C-c whatever` instead. 
Courtesy of [Josh Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173749)

Now to define keybindings that will be active only in term mode, try this:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook
  (lambda () 
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") 'other-window)
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-k") 'kill-buffer)))
```

Comment: Nice, It solves my issue. I'm accepting @Sigma's answer because it is slightly more convenient to configure (no need to duplicate my global-map bindings in the term-raw-map). Thank you!

Comment: @LeMeteore putting these calls in `term-mode-hook` is highly likely not useful: you will end up reinstalling those keys every time the mode is activated, instead of doing it only once.

Comment: @Sigma you're right. I was in fact trying to quickly find a solution. Your answer is indeed more convenient.

Comment: Good point on using `term-raw-map` instead of `term-mode-map` as it's the default keymap *(alternatively, a user may put keybindings to both maps)*. It isn't obvious and for some reason I didn't find this answer till I wrote a question and almost sent it. Anyway, [I sent fixes to the `term-mode` documentation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-29&id=f48babb1120343f211367a1b5854dc7740c3091d), so hopefully it would be less of a problem for future users.